# Please Someone solve this nodemon error in react.js MERN STACK node.js

Tags: reactjs, mern, nodemon

[enven if i install modemon globaly same king of error came.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxOO4.png)

[i was expecting this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uddYG.png)

nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon .\index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Did you install `nodemon` globally?

Answer (score -1):

use `cmd` and not `powershel`. if didnt help - make sure you're running the `nodemon` command in the server folder and not on the client.
if still no - put the command inside the `package.json` file, under the scripts section, then run the script. like -`"start":"nodemon index.js"` then to run it - make a`npm run start` command instead of `nodemon index`

Comment: What difference would it make if one used `cmd` instead of `powershell`? And if nodemon isn't installed globally, it's more or less irrelevant where you try to execute it ...

Comment: Thanks for asking. CMD has a different scope, which nodemon never worked for me on Powershell but did work on CMD/bash.
About the script - when you have issue with npm cache and it doesn't finds your global install - you still can run npm scripts that do get access to the files (and in case that's installed locally only - this is the only way to run it)